# C++, function that checks if software runs on 32-bit or 64-bit system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

As I explained in many questions, I'm trying to move a software from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system.
I had [some problem with malloc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172436/c-error-on-ms-visual-studio-windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-javaw-exe/10227939#10227939), but now I solved it by correcting a parameter.

In that part of my code, if I run on a 32-bit system, I can use:

> (int**) malloc (const * sizeof(int))

But, on a 64-bit system, I have to use:

> (int**) malloc (const * sizeof(int64_t))

I'd like to manage these crossroads with an **if()** condition, so I need a **boolean isIt64system()** function that behaves this way:

> if(isIt64system()) then *[64-bit code]*
>
> else *[32-bit code]*

Does this function exist in C++?
Is there any function that tells me if software's running on a 32-bit system or 64-bit system?

Comment: So you mean to say you are running the same binary on the two different platforms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining 32 vs 64 bit in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c)

Comment: The correct way to do it would be `(int**) malloc (count * sizeof(int*))` or even better `new int*[count]`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the host operating system with how your application is built.  You can't redefine malloc at runtime.  It must be compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit, and in either case it will take an argument of type size_t.  On PC platforms size_t will be 32 bits wide if compiled as 32-bit, or 64 bits if compiled as 64-bit.  There's no way to change that at runtime.

Comment: @Henrik: or even better to use vectors ;)

Comment: Not an exact dupe since Davide's justification allows for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than writing two size-dependent branches, just write one correct, portable code path. In your case:

```
(int**)malloc(count*sizeof(int*));
```

This will work correctly regardless of the sizeof of `int*` on your system.

---

Postscript: As you can see from this literal answer to your question, you are better off not having an if:

```
if(sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int))
    x = (int**)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
else if (sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int64_t))
    x = (int**)malloc(count*sizeof(int64_t));
```

Hopefully you can see how absurdly redundant that code is, and how it should be replaced by a single well-constructed `malloc` call.

Comment: Thanks. Would other solution `new int*[count]` the same?

Comment: That solution would also be correct, and would be more appropriate for a C++ program. Note that any pointer allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]`, any pointer allocated with `malloc()` must be released with `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler will have preprocessor defines that will let you check 32bit versus 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use something like this

```
#ifdef __LP64__
    <64bit code>
#else
    <32bit code>
#endif
```

But if you really need a function for it then this should work.

```
bool is64bit() {
    if (sizeof(int*) == 4) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```