# C++ combination of fstream and new triggering random breakpoints, but only occasionally

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator, fstream

Apologies if this is a little vague, but I really don't know what's happening.

Since I've added some file reading functionality to a simulation program it has started triggering breakpoints in various different parts of the code. Sometimes within the 'new' function, sometimes when it tries to open a pipe for gnuplot commands, and sometimes just at the end of the program.

Because none of this was happening before, and after a bit of debugging, I think that the cause is something to do with the combination of the file reading and dynamic memory allocation. But beyond that I really don't know what is causing this, especially because it only happens occasionally. Can anyone offer any advice on this?

EDIT: It's been pointed out that this isn't actually a breakpoint, but a visual studio error indicating a problem with the heap allocation. Similar to [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172436/c-error-on-ms-visual-studio-windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-javaw-exe), so I may just have to go away and check all of my dynamic memory pointers. This being said, I would still appreciate it if anyone has any advice they could offer about this.

Below are code snippets of the functions that I've added.

```
string input = "C:/Users/ME/Documents/Data/Cilium/Raw/size.dat";

ifstream fsRead(input.c_str());

//cout << "Reading file: " << "\n\t" << input.c_str() << endl;

j = 0;

while (fsRead >> inval)
{
    Numpoints[j] = inval;

    //cout << Numpoints[j] << endl;
    j++;
}

j = 0;

fsRead.close();

...

[ITERATION LOOP]
{
int phase = it%T;

Ns = nearbyint(Numpoints[2 * phase + 0]);

ds = Numpoints[2 * phase + 1];

s = new double[5 * Ns];

if (phase == 0) phase = T;

    input += to_string(phase);

    input += ".dat";

    ifstream fsRead(input.c_str());

    //cout << "Reading file: " << "\n\t" << input.c_str() << endl;

    j = 0;

    while (fsRead >> inval)
    {
        if (j % 5 == 0) s[j] = inval + XDIM/2;
        else s[j] = inval;

        j++;
    }

    j = 0;

    fsRead.close();

...

delete s;
}
```

Comment: You really should not be using `new`.  If you need an array of a run time size then use a `std::vector`.  That said we will need a [mcve] here.

Comment: I have to use 'new' because I'm sending variables to CUDA kernels. Regarding the example, I have tried but I can't reproduce these errors with anything other than this program and it's huge.

Comment: You still don't have to use new.  You can get a pointer to the underlying data in the vector using the `data` function or `&vector_name[0]`.

Comment: I am going to guess: You are debugging optimised code and/or code linked with duplicate COMDAT folding or similar. I.e. two functions have identical machine code, therefore sticking a breakpoint in one breaks in them all.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've tried that but it doesn't work with what I'm doing. Besides which using vectors significantly slowed down my program even before it was parallelised.

Comment: @Ben says No to Politics on SO Thats not the case. None of the breakpoints being triggered are in functions that I've written myself

Comment: That's irrelevant to my point. If you've linked statically they can still be duplicates of a function where you've set a breakpoint. Unset all your breakpoints, see if it goes away.

Comment: @Ben says No to Politics Just tried unsetting all my breakpoints, but no change I'm afraid

Comment: So are you sure they are breakpoints? Not some other type of exception?

Comment: @Ben says No to Politics on SO the message from Visual Studio: CUDA_IBLB_05.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Comment: That's something completely different. Putting that information in the question would have been a good start! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172436/c-error-on-ms-visual-studio-windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-javaw-exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ error on Ms Visual Studio: "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in javaw.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172436/c-error-on-ms-visual-studio-windows-has-triggered-a-breakpoint-in-javaw-exe)